# OpenSSL::SSL in CMake not found

Tags: c++, cmake, openssl

I'm trying to make a discord bot, doing this for the 1st time. I'm using Code::Blocks, when I run the Generate button in CMake it outputs an error:

```
   CMake Error at sleepy-discord/sleepy_discord/CMakeLists.txt:1 (add_library):
   Target "sleepy-discord" links to target "OpenSSL::SSL" but the target was
   not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
   target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
```

Here is the content of CMakeLists.txt file:

```
#CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.6)
project(DiscordBot)

add_executable(DiscordBot main.cpp)

add_subdirectory(sleepy-discord)
target_link_libraries(DiscordBot sleepy-discord)
```

Comment: You could use a package manager like [Conan](https://conan.io/) or use the native OpenSSL from your OS. What do you want to use? Please show use the CMake file of the subdirectory.

Comment: The library sleepy-discord you are linking your project DiscordBot against is using another library named OpenSSL but misses the linking part in its own CMakelists.txt. Either the library OpenSSL isn't installed on your computer, or if you are the author of the library it could miss a call to find_package(OpenSSL).

Comment: What version of CMake are you using? Do you have OpenSSL installed on your machine?

Comment: @Elias: The sleepy-discord project [has call](https://github.com/yourWaifu/sleepy-discord/blob/master/sleepy_discord/CMakeLists.txt#L59) to `find_package(OpenSSL)`. It seems that for some reason this call has not create `OpenSSL::SSL` IMPORTED target. While according to [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/module/FindOpenSSL.html) this call should create the target (this is true since CMake 3.4, and the code in the question uses `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)`).